# Simplest way of programmatically creating a DataGridView with X columns by Y rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In C# Winforms, I'd like to use a DataGridView as a simple widget to store information to display to the user. To this end, I'd like to create a table of say, 5x10 cells.

After some research, solutions tend to allow adding just one row or column at a time. I'd like the whole grid created initially and straight away, so I can start populating it with data, like you would with a standard C# 2D array.

What's the simplest way of going about this? A function header could look like this:

`createCells(DataGridView dgv, int cols, int rows) {}`

It should be quick and amenable to changing the cols and rows to a larger or smaller number later on if need be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way, there might an error like:

> Sum Of The Columns' FillWeight Values Cannot Exceed 65535

To avoid it, set `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `false`, and set `FillWeight` to `1` for each column generated:

```
dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
{
    dgv.Columns.Add("col" + i, "column " + i);
    dgv.Columns[i - 1].FillWeight = 1;
}
for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    dgv.Rows.Add();
```

Comment: And say if I want to create a smaller table after that and replace it over this old one? Is there a way to delete all cells or similar?

Comment: Aha found out how: `dgv.Rows.Clear(); dgv.Columns.Clear();`. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can do by using for loops in this way:

```
    private DataGridView DGV_Creation(DataGridView dgv, int columns, int rows)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            dgv.Columns.Add("col" + i, "column " + i);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            dgv.Rows.Add();
        }
        return dgv;
    }
```

Call it with:

```
this.dataGridView1 = DGV_Creation(dataGridView1, 5, 10); // 5 columns, 10 rows (empty rows)
```

or:

```
    private void DGV_Creation(ref DataGridView dgv, int columns, int rows)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            dgv.Columns.Add("col" + i, "column " + i);
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
            dgv.Rows.Add();
    }
```

call it with:

```
DGV_Creation(ref this.dataGridView1, 5, 10); //5 columns, 10 rows (empty rows)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Does the trick instantly, fairly fast (a few seconds for 10000x20 cells), and was less code than I was fearing. I'll probably tick this soon.

Comment: I have added just a bit different solution, by using ref keyword (no need to pass dataGridView object back (like dgv = ...), but exactly the way you wanted

Comment: Thanks, I don't think ref is needed at all, since it's already sent by ref?